# Convert CSS transition to Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I want to convert my CSS transition to Jquery

My CSS transition is this :

```
.classname { 
width : 470px;
transition: all 2s ease 0s;
}

.classname:hover {
width : 700px;
}
```

this mean the CSS code , changes the width of element .

So, How can i do that with Jquery ?

Comment: People often look for the `jQuery to CSS`. BTW, take a look at [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xjvj7/1/

Answer (score 1):

What all you need to do is to add an event on your class, and then attach animate method to it. you can see these kind of examples of [learn.jquery.com](http://learn.jquery.com) as well.

```
$(".classname").on({
    mouseenter : function(){
        $(this).animate({
            width : 700
        });
    },
    mouseleave : function(){
        $(this).animate({
            width : 470
        });
    }
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w5pRy/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should try [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) with [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). try this:

```
$(".classname").hover( function(){
 $(this).animate({width : '700px'});
}, function(){
 $(this).animate({width : '470px'});
})
```

[Here is working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xjjtw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.classname', function(){
   $(this).animate({width : 700});
}).on('mouseleave', '.classname', function(){
  $(this).animate({width : 470});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".classname").hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: "300px"
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: "100px"
        });

    });
```

working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/UwKH3/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".classname").hover( function(){
   $(this).delay(2000).animate({width : 700px});
   }, function(){
   $(this).delay(2000).animate({width : 470px});
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/QGc8h/

**HTML:**

```
css:<br/>
<div class='classname'>some content</div>
jquery:<br/>
<div class='jqclassname'>some content</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.jqclassname, .classname {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width : 470px;
}

.classname { 
    transition: all 2s ease 0s;
}

.classname:hover {
    width : 700px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $('.jqclassname').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({width: 700}, 2000);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({width: 470}, 2000);
        }
    )
});
```